# Linking probability measure to classical definition of probability when sampling from finite population

Tags: probability, measure-theory, sampling, sampling-theory

Consider a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ where $\Omega$ is finite, $\mathcal{F}$ is the power set of $\Omega$ and $\mathbb{P}(F)\equiv |F|/|\Omega|$ $\forall F \in \mathcal{F}$.

In what follows:

$$
\Omega\equiv \{1,2,3\}
$$
$$
\mathcal{F}\equiv \Big\{\emptyset, \Omega, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}\Big\}
$$ 
$$
\mathbb{P}(\emptyset)=0, \mathbb{P}(\Omega)=1, \mathbb{P}(\{1\})=\mathbb{P}(\{2\})=\mathbb{P}(\{3\})=1/3, \mathbb{P}(\{1,2\})=\mathbb{P}(\{1,3\})=\mathbb{P}(\{2,3\})=2/3
$$

Suppose we draw from $\Omega$ a simple random sample of size $N=2$.

**1)** It is intuitive to say that "The *probability* of drawing $\{1,2\}$ is $\frac{1}{\binom{|\Omega|}{N}}=\frac{1}{3}$". However, what is the formal  link between this *probability* (which seems to me somehow related to the [classical definition of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_definition_of_probability)) and the measure $\mathbb{P}$ defined above?

**2)** I found in some books the following: let $W_i$ be a *random variable* equal to $1$ if the $i$th element of $\Omega$ is drawn and zero otherwise. Then, the probability that $W_i=1$ is $\frac{\binom{|\Omega|-1}{N-1}}{\binom{|\Omega|}{N}}$. But, again, what is the exact measure-theoretic definition of $W_i$ as random variable with respect to the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$?

---

I am puzzled to find a relation. I was wondering whether the only solution would be to define **ANOTHER probability space**  $(\Omega_1,\mathcal{F}_1,\mathbb{P}_1)$ where
$$
\Omega_1\equiv (A,B,C) \hspace{1cm} \text{[all possible outcomes of the drawing experiment]}
$$
$$
\mathcal{F}_1\equiv \Big\{\emptyset, \Omega_1, \{A\}, \{B\}, \{C\}, \{A,B\}, \{A,C\}, \{B,C\}\Big\}
$$ 
$$
\mathbb{P}_1(\emptyset)=0, \mathbb{P}_1(\Omega)=1, \mathbb{P}_1(\{A\})=\mathbb{P}_1(\{B\})=\mathbb{P}_1(\{C\})=1/3, \mathbb{P}_1(\{A,B\})=\mathbb{P}_1(\{A,C\})=\mathbb{P}_1(\{B,C\})=2/3
$$
where $\mathbb{P}_1$ is somehow related to $\mathbb{P}$.

We then define the random variable 
$$
W:\Omega_1\rightarrow \{\{(1,2)\}, \{(2,3)\}, \{(1,3)\}\} \hspace{1cm}\text{[outcome of drawing experiment]}
$$
with 
$$
W(A)=\{(1,2)\}, W(B)=\{ (2,3)\}, W(C)=\{(1,3)\}
$$
Hence, $\mathbb{P}_1(W=\{(1,2\})=\frac{1}{3}$ as expected.

We can also defined another random variable
$$
W_1: \Omega_1\rightarrow \{1,0\}
$$
$$
W_1(A)=1, W_1(B)=0, W_1(C)=1 \hspace{1cm}\text{[$1$ if first element of $\Omega$ is drawn]}
$$
Hence, $\mathbb{P}_1(W_1=1)=\frac{2}{3}$ as expected.

Comment: You are right, making a new probability space is the way to go.

Comment: @littleO If you draw two items from $\Omega$ without replacement (i.e., simultaneously), then you have $3$ possible outcomes and $1$ chance to get $\{1,2\}$

Comment: @STF But that's not what your $\mathbb{P}$ gives. The probability it assigns to every subset $S$ of $\Omega$ corresponds to the probability "if I pick an element $x$ of $\Omega$ uniformly at random, what is the probability that $x\in S$?"

Comment: So indeed, the probability space you have does not correspond to the experiment you want to capture.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, the reason of starting from a different probability space is that in statistics we often assume that the sample space is the population of agents and we draw from this population.

Comment: @STF can you make an answer out of the second part of your question? cuz it is pretty much the correct answer.

Comment: @STF If you draw (without replacement) at set of $N$ people from that population, your sample space actually is the set of all size-$N$ subsets of the population. (population and sample space are not the same here
)